# Typeerror an integer is requred

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, feature-selection

Can any one help me to solve an error in this python code that I faced when I tried to apply pymrmr in feature selection in this link https://pypi.org/project/pymrmr/
(Note: using python 3.9 but the used language is 3.6)

The code :

```
import pandas as pd

In [2]: import pymrmr

In [3]: df = pd.read_csv('abalone.csv')

In [4]: pymrmr.mRMR(df, 'MIQ', 10)
```

The error :

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3340/2745717911.py in <module>
----> 1 pymrmr.mRMR(df, 'MIQ', 10)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymrmr\pymrmr.pyx in pymrmr.mRMR()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymrmr.cp39-win_amd64.pyd in vector.from_py.__pyx_convert_vector_from_py_int()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymrmr.cp39-win_amd64.pyd in vector.from_py.__pyx_convert_vector_from_py_int()

TypeError: an integer is required
```

(Note: my python version is 3.9 but the used programming language in the website is 3.6)

Comment: What does your csv file contain ?

Comment: "abalone" data from kaggle ( https://www.kaggle.com/search?q=abalone)

Comment: Edit:  In [3]: df = pd.read_csv('abalone.csv')   not    In [3]: df = pd.read_csv('test_colon_s3.csv')

Comment: Then documentation says "Data should be provided already discretised, as defined in the original paper". Did you do this?

Comment: Yes but  I am not sure how to apply my dataset –

Comment: Is the python version may affect on running the module